# Where are dangerous wild animals in Untamed Wilds?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Whenever I deploy in Untamed Wilds, even single dwarves can hunt freely with almost no danger. Sometimes there are stray bears, but mostly it's just elephants.

What I want is a map which is not evil (i.e. no zombies and necromancers), but I'm scared to let my dwarfs go outside fortress walls without a group of heavily armed  soldiers.

Comment: Only about half of evil biomes are reanimating, so you won't necessarily be overrun with the undead. The weather may also be an issue that your military can't deal with. Overall though, try embarking on a glacier for harder without going evil.

Comment: That's different definition of "hard". I'd like to train my military defence skills, but goblins usually arrive only in N years. I want to fight something from the day 1.

Comment: Glaciers have more dangerous creatures on them, on average. It does come hand in hand with difficulty for other reasons, unfortunately. I assume you are using the highest setting for number of beasts at worldgen already?